# C# Image over another image

Tags: c#, winforms, image

I have a picturebox with a fixed sized image (256x256) generated by the program.  I have another smaller image as a resource.  What I want to do is when my cursor is over the image and I hold down the mouse button, the smaller image "anchors" with the mouse pointer so it moves around with it.  If I let go of the mouse button, the smaller image will stay in that position on top of the bigger image.  The smaller image is basically a marker, something like an X or O.

I was thinking of having a second picturebox on top of the first picturebox but I can't make it transparent.  Or redrawing the image with the smaller image on top of it and reloading the image into the picturebox, but I'm not sure how to do that and I think it's going to be pretty slow redrawing it each time I move the mouse.

So how can I have a marker image move around on top of a bigger image and have it stay there?

Comment: I'm afraid for having this kind of custom solution you should avoid using standart controls and implement your own with its own drawing style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your control for this instead of using `PictureBox`.  PictureBox should be used ONLY for fixed images on the form, nothing else.

Instead, derive your control from `UserControl`.  Turn on double buffering for it.  In `OnPaint` method, first draw your background picture, then your marker picture after it.  Don't worry, it WON'T be slow and it WILL work as it should.

When you release the mouse, update background picture by drawing your marker picture on it.

Since every sentence here is a little discovery by itself, hope you'll have a good time coding your little game :)